# Validate display:none dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, validation

i use this plugin:
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Is it possible to validate select-fields with style="display:none" ?

I need this because another Plugin style my dropdown and set the original select-field to display:none and create an own with div and ul.

In this case select name=xxx wasn't validated :-(

```
<select style="display: none;" sb="20200222" name="xxx" class="300" id="yyy">
<option selected="selected" value="">Choose</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div class="sbHolder" id="sbHolder_20200222">
<ul style="top: 38px; max-height: 193px; display: none;" class="sbOptions" id="sbOptions_20200222">
<li><a rel="" href="#">Choose</a></li>
<li><a rel="1" href="#1">1</a></li>
<li><a rel="2" href="#2">2</a></li>
<li><a rel="3" href="#3">3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try using the `ignore` option? This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466643/jquery-validate-enable-validation-for-hidden-fields

Comment: No, i don't want to ignore it, i want to validate it.

Comment: I know. The default behavior is to ignore. That's why you use the option to set ignore to false.

Comment: Ah ok, what is the right syntax?

Comment: $("#myform").validate({
   ignore: []
})

Comment: If i submit the form the "display:none" original dropdowns were shown. Only if i set the css value display:none to !important with firebug, the original select-fields hide.

Comment: Ok this is a BUG in the plugin. Changed some code in there and now i got it. Thank you very much Rob!

Answer (score 0):

using ignore is the best thing to do.

```
$("#myform").validate({ ignore: [] })
```

that is the best solution.