# jQuery Validate - Enable validation for given hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

In 2011, [jQuery Validate - Enable validation for hidden fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466643/jquery-validate-enable-validation-for-hidden-fields) recommended solution to validate hidden fields using validation plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/ version 1.9 was to set the `ignore` property to an empty array.

Using version 1.13.1, is this still the preferred way to do so?

If I only wish to validate one specific hidden input, and use the default for all other inputs, is there another way to do so?  I tried adding a custom validation method, however, the hidden attribute of the input prevented it from being triggered.  Maybe instead of setting the `ignore` attribute to an empty array, could it be set to something that ignores all hidden inputs except for the one I wish validated?

Comment: Yes, it still works that way.  And yes, you can specify that it ignore only certain hidden inputs and not others... it's just a matter of using the proper selectors.  Based on the question, I guess you have not tried anything yet.

Comment: Also see:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20287614/594235

Comment: Hey Sparky,  Good to see you are still helping out on this topic after several years!  Thanks, I will look into selecting all but the specific element.  Note that I had tried for quite a bit before posing this question.  Thanks again.  EDIT.  Thanks for the second post.  Agree it was duplicated.  Sorry