# How can I make two ignore in jquery validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to validate input type hidden

I add this :

```
product: { 
    ignore: "",
    rules: {
        description: {
            required: true
        },
        ...
    },
},
```

It works. I success validate input type hidden

But in my form, it need to validate summernote too

I get some reference to validate summernote and the ignore must changed like this :

```
ignore: ":hidden:not(#summernote),.note-editable.panel-body"
```

It works. But the validate input type hidden not works

So if I use : `ignore: ""`, the summernote validate not works

If I use : `ignore: ":hidden:not(#summernote),.note-editable.panel-body"`, the input type hidden not works

How do I merge it so that both (input type hidden and summernote) can work fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ignore` in this plugin means to "not validate"

So `ignore: ""` means to "ignore nothing"; validate **everything**, including hidden fields.

> I get some reference to validate summernote and the ignore must changed like this :

```
ignore: ":hidden:not(#summernote),.note-editable.panel-body"
```

This line is saying to "ignore" two things from validation...

1. `:hidden:not(#summernote)`
2. `.note-editable.panel-body`

> the input type hidden not works

Of course.  Because your first part, `:hidden:not(#summernote)`, is telling it to ignore everything hidden except for `#summernote`.

So if you want to validate ***all*** hidden fields, then you cannot put `:hidden` inside of `ignore`!

Only list the things here that you do not want to validate:

```
ignore: ".note-editable.panel-body"
```

Comment: It's still not perfect. I use summernote to crud(there exist form add & edit data). If I add data, it works. But if I edit data, the required does not works. On the console exist error : `uncaught typeerror: cannot read property 'settings' of undefined`. I try change this : `ignore: ":hidden:not(#summernote),.note-editable.panel-body"`, it works. But the problem is the input type hidden not validate

Comment: @SuccessMan, I cannot see your DOM or HTML structure so therefore I have no idea what you’ll need to ignore and what you need to validate.  However, based on what little was provided in the OP, I’ve fully answered your question.

Comment: @SuccessMan, so do you want to validate hidden fields or not?  If you want to validate them, then you cannot have `:hidden` in the `ignore` list.   You've shown us no hidden fields, no HTML markup at all, so it would be literally impossible for me to know how to write your code for you.  Otherwise, I think I have explained the `ignore` option thoroughly enough for you to be able to figure out the proper jQuery selectors for yourself.

Comment: Yes, I want to validate hidden field. But if I use this : `ignore: ".note-editable.panel-body"`, on the edit data, there exist error : `uncaught typeerror: cannot read property 'settings' of undefined`

Comment: @SuccessMan, that is a generic error that could be triggered by anything in this plugin.  You have not shown nearly enough code to solve that.  Activate the `debug` option of the plugin and read the console log.   Also create a jsFiddle demo AND show enough code in the OP to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Okay. I will try it. But whether it can if I add operator ternary (condition) in ignone list?
 So if form add data, then the ignore : `ignore: ".note-editable.panel-body"`. If form edit data, then the ignore : `ignore: ":hidden:not(#summernote),.note-editable.panel-body"`

Comment: @SuccessMan, of course not!   You can only add a comma separated list of jQuery style selectors to that parameter, not a function.

Comment: Okay. Btw, can I ignore hidden inputs with a particular class? So only ignore some class on the input hidden

Comment: @SuccessMan, it will ignore whatever you put inside `ignore`.  I thought that part was clear.  In other words, put the class in `ignore` and it does not care if it’s hidden.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287567/ignore-all-hidden-div-but-not-one-in-jquery-validation. Seems it can

Comment: @SuccessMan, seriously, you’re totally misunderstanding how this works.  The DEFAULT value of `ignore` is `:hidden` and ANYTHING you put inside `ignore` will OVERRIDE thIs default.  So if you only use a class, then it will only match the class, whether hidden or not.  Get it now?   I’m done. Good luck.

Comment: Okay. I just try it directly on my project and it works. Thanks for your help