# jquery validator plugin with display:none form elements

Tags: jquery, plugins, block, validation

I'm using the validator plugin found [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to validate a form.

Problem I'm having is if I put the following around a form input element the validation fails:

```
<div style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="test" /></div>
```

I need this because I'm using other UI control layers for the input elements and don't want them visible.

It works on inline and block elements, but I need it to be hidden. Is there anyway to get around this?

Thanks for any feedback

**Update:**

I'm mostly validating select option fields, with django (ie: {{form.select_option_element}} )

So effectively:

```
<div style="display:none;">
    {{form.select_option_element}}
</div>
```

...doesn't work

Right after posting I seem to solve it with:

```
<div style="visibility: hidden; height: 0;">
     {{form.select_option_element}}
</div>
```

It then allows me to validate the field.

Comment: Please don't place the accepted answer within your question. Questions  and answers should be kept separate.

Comment: no problem, not used to the place yet

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Validate - Enable validation for hidden fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466643/jquery-validate-enable-validation-for-hidden-fields)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

From the 1.9.0 Change Log of [jQuery Validate](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/changelog.md#190):

> - Fixed #189 - :hidden elements are now ignored by default

To turn it back on simply do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        ignore: []
    });
});
```

Make sure that this appears **before** you call the actual validation plugin in your code.

I hope this helps!

Comment: ah, thank you. That works quite nicely. I will use this instead.

Comment: Why an empty array, not an empty string?

Answer (score 4):

I like the answer of @dSquared but unfortunately 'ignore'-property will be reseted for every form's validator on page. In some cases it doesnt need.

I use this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $form = $("#some-form");

    $form.validate().settings.ignore = []; // ! Say to validator dont ignore hidden-elements on concrete form.

    $('#button-send').click(function () {
        if ($form.valid()) { .. }
    });

    // !! apply plugin's initializers which will hide origin elements (it can be CLEditor or Choosen plugins)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the style attribute to the input element? So instead of wrapping it with a **div**, try:

```
<input type="text" name="test" value="" style="display: none;" />
```

Comment: Nevermind, blanked out for a minute.

Here is how I solved it:

    <div style="visibility: hidden; height: 0;">
      <input type="text" name="test" />
    </div>

Comment: I'm using django ModelForms, I forgot to mention I mostly validating select option list.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do.

1) you can statically set value, which does not fail validation, for this input field like

```
<div style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="test" value="default" /></div>
```

2) If you want to neglate this value in your validation method.

I would appreciate if you could provide more detail code.

Comment: What I mean is that the validator doesn't even recognize the field, not the validation process itself.

Comment: Well I saw the way you fixed it. Anyway good to see u got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another form to solve this problem is changing the `display: none` to `visibility: hidden`.

Eg: `<input type="text" name="test" value="" style="visibility: hidden;" />`