# jquery validate radio input with css background hack

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

I like using jquery validate to validate my forms, I have to use a background image for the radio input.

below is the html, css and jquery for the validation.

I decided to add a simple radio:  and added it to the rules and it displayed the error message when I tried to submit the form, only for that input, but not for upgrade or route radio fields.

This makes me believe the img background hack for a radio field is causing the validation not to work. Probably because I have display: none; for the radio input type in the css.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="u1" name="upgrade" value="1" />
<label for="u1"><span></span></label>
```

CSS:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label {
    color:#f2f2f2;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: -3px;
}

input[type="radio"] + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 38px;
    height: 28px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url('../images/sub-vote-box-checkbox.png') no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
    background:url('../images/sub-vote-box-checkbox-checked.png') no-repeat;
}
```

JavaScript:

```javascript
$("#vote-route-upgrade-form").validate({
    rules: {
        route: {
            required: true,
        },
        upgrade: {
            required: true,
        },
    },

    submitHandler: function() {
        $('#vote-modal').modal('hide');
        $('#thanks-modal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: css, affecting the validation of a form? that doesn't sound right to me. There are a few trailing commas in your js that will break oldIE

Comment: @KevinB I commented out display: none; on the first css rule and it now shows the error message, but I need to display the background image in place of the traditional looking radio fields.

Comment: my point was that the validation should be unaffected. Could it affect how the validation displays errors? Yes! but that's configurable.

Comment: Also see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466643/jquery-validate-enable-validation-for-hidden-fields/8565769#8565769

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308138/jquery-validator-plugin-with-displaynone-form-elements) (and upvote it :)).

Elements with display:none are ignored by `validate` plugin.

Comment: or, close this question as a duplicate