# jquery-validate: validation not working on an ui-accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery-validate to validate a form. Jquery-validate works well and doesn't send form if a required field is empty. But if my form is into an jquery-ui accordion, the form is sent.

Rules:

```
$("#form_master").validate({
    rules: {
        categorie: "required"
    }});`
```

Accordion:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ autoHeight: true, navigation: true, });
```

You can try it here : http://jsfiddle.net/Zv76Y/4/

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery validation not working on an accordion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878476/jquery-validation-not-working-on-an-accordion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because, the validator by default ignores hidden elements.

So when you use an accordion the input fields are hidden so they are not validated

```
$("#form_master").validate({
    ignore: [],
    rules: {
        categorie: "required"
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.is(":radio")) error.appendTo(element.parent().next().next());
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pu635/)

Note: You may have to highlight the accordion tags with error so that users will now that there is error

Comment: @Antrax and Arun, as per the developer, the proper way to disable this behavior is `ignore: []` ~ See:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235