# password field not validated with jquery validation 1.10 with placeholder 2.0.7 on any IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, placeholder, conflicting-libraries

I have question regarding the use of jquery 1.8, jquery validation 1.10 and placeholder 2.0.7 (https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder). I noticed that any version IE skipped the validation of password fields if the placeholder plugin was used. Does anybody have solution for this?

Comment: Please show your code and construct a concise working demo of this problem.

Comment: nevermind I found out how to solve it. Just set $("form").validate({ignore:""}); it's because jquery validation skips validating inputs set to display:none. Placeholder plugin set elements to display:none while not focused thats why it didnt validate. if you set ignore to empty string it wont ignore any inputs. It will even validate disabled inputs i guess.

Comment: Please post that as an answer below and "accept" your answer.  This is most beneficial to the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out how to solve it.

Just set `$("form").validate({ignore:[], ...});` where "form" should be your selector and ... is your options.

The reason for the error is because jquery validation skips validating inputs set to display:none. Placeholder plugin sets password elements to display:none while not focused that is why it passed the validation. If you set ignore to [] it will override the default behavior of jquery validation which is not to validate display:none elements.

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235).  You may want to update your answer and code accordingly.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235