# jquery validation plugin: validating hidden input, skips required input text

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate, hidden-field

I'm trying to validate a form, that has both hidden and not hidden input. I added in the form validation settings the line ignore: "" to validate the hidden input, but doing so, it doesn't validate required text input that is before it, but only when put AFTER it. 
Another thing that happens, is that the validation of firstname works on blur after the first submit (but still it doesn't block the submit itself)....

Here is my code, and a link to js fiddle [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/68uu5/2/):

JS:

```
    var countries = [{label:"Vanuatu", code:"VU"},
        {label:"Ecuador", code:"EC"}];    
    $().ready(function() {
$('#country').autocomplete({
    source : function(request, response) {
        var matcher = new RegExp('^'+$.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
        response($.grep(countries, function(element, index) {
            return matcher.test(element.label);
        }));
    },
    delay : 0,
    change : function(event, ui) {
        $('#countryCode').val(ui.item ? ui.item.code : '');
    }
});
$("#signupForm").validate({
    ignore: "",
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            required: true
        },
        lastname: {
            required: true
        },
        country: {
            required: true
        },
        countryCode: {
            required: function(element){
                return $("#signupForm").validate().element( "#country" );
            }
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },  
    messages: {
        firstname: "Please enter your first name",
        lastname: "Please enter your last name",
        country: "Please select a country",
        countryCode: "Please select a valid country",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert("fine!");
    }
});
```

});
HTML form:

```
    <form id="signupForm" method="post" name="" action="">
<p>
        <label for="firstname"></label>
        <input class="inputText" type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
    </p>
            <p>
        <label for="country"></label>
        <input class="inputText" type="text" id="country" name="country" placeholder="Country"/>

        <input type="hidden" name="countryCode" id="countryCode" />
    </p>
                <p>
        <label for="lastname"></label>
        <input class="inputText" type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
                    </p>
                    <p>
        <label for="email"></label>
        <input class="inputText" type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                        </p>
                        <p>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" id="signupButton" value="SUBMIT" />   
                        </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: what is the logic for `countryCode` validation? Is it required only if `country` is specified?

Comment: yes, since I need to validate that a valid country is selected from the autocomplete. In this way I have the validation that country is filled, and the countryCode is selected (the countryCode is needed server side).

Comment: Can you check http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/68uu5/3/ and see whether your requirement is met

Comment: Also see this answer for the proper way to use the `ignore` option.  Should be `ignore: []` See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the `countryCode` validation

You can try

```
countryCode: {
    required: function(element){
        return $("#country").val().length > 0;
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/68uu5/3/)

Comment: great thanks a lot! I thought the .validate() on country element would have done that.... do you think it's a bug to report to the developers?

Comment: I think the `element` method is designed to be called with the callback methods, any way you can check with the developers