# How to validate hidden fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

I have a form name="myform" but there is exists hidden fields
So i want to validate those fields also, 
how to validate hidden fields using jquery form validation?

Comment: please provide such with some codes

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466643/jquery-validate-enable-validation-for-hidden-fields

Comment: which jQuery validation plugin are you using now ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery.validate` plugin that allow to validate hidden fields.

Just set `ignore : false;` or `$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: '' });` and that will allow you to validate hidden fields.

**Official Site** : http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: As per developer, `ignore: []` is the proper syntax.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235

Answer (score 0):

override the ignore variable and set it to empty:

```
$("#form").validate({
    ignore: "",
    rules: {
        something: {
            number:true,
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: As per developer, `ignore: []` is the proper syntax.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235