# Bootstrap Radiobutton int jquery validation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, radio-button

I've tried a couple different options while trying to avoid setting a default selected value.

Option 1

```
<div class="control-group">
    <h4>Text</h4>
    <div class="controls">
        <div hidden="hidden" >@Html.EditorFor(m => m.pc.PS1)</div>                            
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle-name="pc.PS1" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
        <button type="button" value="11" class="btn@((Model.pc.PS1 == 11) ? " active" : string.Empty )" data-toggle="button">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" value="12" class="btn@((Model.pc.PS1 == 12) ? " active" : string.Empty )" data-toggle="button">No</button>
        <button type="button" value="13" class="btn@((Model.pc.PS1 == 13) ? " active" : string.Empty )" data-toggle="button">N/A</button>
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.pc.PS1)
</div>
```

Option 2

```
<div class="control-group">
     <h4>Text</h4>
     <div class="controls">
         @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.pc.F1FallsRiskAssessmentFRASE)
         <div class="btn-group" data-toggle-name="pc.PS2" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
         <button type="button" value="11" class="btn@((Model.pc.PS2== 11) ? " active" : string.Empty )" data-toggle="button">Yes</button>
         <button type="button" value="12" class="btn@((Model.pc.PS2== 12) ? " active" : string.Empty )" data-toggle="button">No</button>
         <button type="button" value="13" class="btn@((Model.pc.PS2== 13) ? " active" : string.Empty )" data-toggle="button">N/A</button>
         </div>
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.pc.PS2)
      </div>
</div>

$('#ctFRM').validate({
            rules: {
                "pc.PS1": { required: true, minlength: 2 },
                "pc_PS2": { required: true, minlength: 2 },
```

The Id for the hidden on the page is pc_PS2 but the name is pc.PS2 with using firebug script tab and putting a break point over this shows the default value being 0 when validation is pc_PS2 but no validation messages put up regardless of "." or "_".

They do work for a textbox input which uses "." in the validation rules and "_" with setting a mask on it.

I had tried to use required validation on the radiobuttons with each having a value of 1/2/3 but since the page defaults the hidden with value 0 then it doesn't trigger the required true validation.

Next I tried setting the option values as 11/12/13 so they have a length of 2 so I can use minlength 2 to prevent submit but that doesn't kick in until change.

So I'm left with the back up option of unobtrusive validation or setting up an onclick for each button set for each question in the hopes of getting normal string required validation to work on another set of hidden values.

Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: Show the _rendered_ HTML code.  Secondly, when declaring rules inside of `.validate()`, you can only use the `name` attribute.  Third, you cannot validate hidden fields without setting the option `ignore: []`.  And finally, you're all over place and I can barely understand what you're trying to tell us... what exactly is your issue/question?

Comment: @Sparky I was trying to show all the different solutions I tried in case 1 was broken but the right 1 to use or at least to show I've tried everything I can think of and had no luck, anyway my point was using the name attribute doesn't get a value in the browser but the Id does. My point in this post was that I wanted to validate bootstrap radiobuttons which were using int values, I'll test the ignore option now and see how it reacts.

Comment: @Sparky putting in the ignore option fixed it so if you make it an answer I'll tick it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to validate any hidden fields you must set the `ignore` option as follows.

```
$('#ctFRM').validate({
    // options and rules,
    ignore: []
});
```

See this for more info:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235