# jQuery validate plugin add methods still running even if not required

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/) and I am adding my own methods like so:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("num", function(num) {
    if(isNaN(num))
        return false;

    return true;
}, "Please enter a valid number");
```

However, even if I don't add the `required` class to a form element, this validation method will still be called and evaluate to false if the user entered nothing. But I would like the behavior to be that if an element does not have the `required` class, it is only called if the user has entered something. Is there anyway to do this? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

So the actual code that I posted above was meant to be a simple example to demonstrate the problem, however now I am putting up the specific example that is giving me issues. Here is the jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/SVwmH/2/

**The HTML**

```
<form method="post">
    <li>
        <label for="2">Mileage</label>
        <input type="text" name="2" id="attr_2" class="non_neg_int"
        value="" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="3">VIN (Vehicle Identification Number)</label>
        <input type="text" name="3"
        id="attr_3" class="vin" maxlength="17" value="" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="submit" />
    </li>
</form>
```

**The JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var validator = $("form").validate({
        onkeyup: false,
        onblur: true,
        ignore: "",
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod("vin", function (vin) {
    if (!(/^[A-HJ-NP-Z0-9]{17}$/.test(vin))) return false;
    return true;
}, "Must be a valid VIN");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("non_neg_int", function (non_neg_int) {
    if (isNaN(non_neg_int) || non_neg_int == null || non_neg_int == "" || non_neg_int < 0 || !is_int(non_neg_int)) return false;

    return true;
}, "Must be a nonnegative integer");

function is_int(value) {
    if ((parseFloat(value) == parseInt(value)) && !isNaN(value)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the rest of your code... `.validate()` along with the form's HTML.  I cannot reproduce the problem as you describe it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Quote OP**:

> "However, even if I don't add the `required` class to a form element,
>   this validation method will still be called and evaluate to false if
>   the user entered nothing."

I cannot reproduce the problem as you describe it.

As posted, an empty field does not call your custom method, nor is the field required.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/mJvA8/**

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("num", function (num) {
        if (isNaN(num)) return false;
        return true;
    }, "Please enter a valid number");

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field1: {
                num: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

---

**EDIT** based on edited OP:

I've found the following issues with your code.   Only some of these items were breaking your code.  The rest are just a matter of good practice.  You can test these one at a time to see for yourself.

**1)**  **There is no such option called** `onblur`.  There's one called `onfocusout` and it's enabled *by default*. If you pass `true` into this, you will break it.  You can only pass `false` to disable it, or pass a custom function to over-ride it.  To keep the default `onfocusout` option enabled, just leave it out entirely.

**2)** Every input element must have a valid `name`, and `name="2"` is invalid.  It cannot start with a number.

**3)** If you want to validate any hidden fields, the `ignore` option must be set to `ignore: []` and not `ignore: ""`.  Otherwise, leave this option out and hidden fields are ignored by default.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235

**4)** I don't understand the point of specifying `value=""` on each element.  Simply leave out the `value` attribute if you're not using it.

**5)**  Instead of writing out all of this...

```
 if (test) return false;
 return true;
```

... you can more simply write one short line:  `return !(test);`  *(I simply added the `!` to flip your particular `test` logic to `return false`, just as you wrote it.)*

**6)**  [As per documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage), you only pass `value`, `element`, and optional `params` into the customMethod function like this:  `.addMethod("myrule", function(value, element, params) { ... }, "message")`.

This syntax alleviates any confusion.  Also, using the rule's name, `"non_neg_int"` in place of the word `"value"` was completely breaking your `non_neg_int` custom method.

If you don't want these rules to be "required", then you have to fix the logic inside the rules.  For example, the `non_neg_int` method is looking for an empty or null field, so of course it's going to give the error message when the field is empty.

On the two rules, I simply added `this.optional(element)` which makes the rule optional.  In other words, if you leave it blank, the rule will do nothing.

```
return this.optional(element) || !(test);
```

There's a working demo below you can tweak as you see fit.

**New Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gVVa8/**

Comment: I've posted a jsfiddle link in my question to show the issue I'm having. The example is slightly different than the one I originally posted.

Comment: Interestingly, here is a new example that mixes my example and yours: http://jsfiddle.net/SVwmH/3/, where your form field does the desired functionality and mine do not.

Comment: @srchulo, you have a bunch of little syntax errors I'm working through.