# JQuery.Validate adding dynamic rules with messages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I have a form on which I am using jquery.validate. I initially call validate with a set of rules and custom messages...

```
$("#formName").validate( {
  rules: {
    myExistingInput: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    myExistingInput: {
      required: "Enter something"
    }
  },
  ignore: null, // include hidden fields (see below)
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    // do stuff
  },
  invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
    // do stuff (some of the fields may have been hidden by a collapsible panel
    // if there is an error on one of those fields, expand the panel so the error
    // becomes visible)
  }
});
```

Later, I dynamically add fields to the form, and add rules for those fields too...

```
$("#formName").append(...);

$("#newInputName").rules("add", {
  required: true,
  messages: {
    required: "Enter something else"
  }
});
```

If I then submit the form, I get an error from within jquery.validate...

> Exception occured when checking element newInputName, check the
>   'messages' method.TypeError: Unable to get property 'call' of
>   undefined or null reference

Debugging in the browser, I can see the error is being thrown from within the "check" function, and that the "method" variable is set to "messages".

If I remove the messages from the call to rules("add",...

```
$("#newInputName").rules("add", {
  required: true
});
```

it works as expected, but obviously I now have no custom error messages.

I have seen many examples here on SO indicating that my syntax is correct. Any suggestions?

BTW: jQuery Validation Plugin - v1.11.0 - 2/4/2013

Comment: FYI: Also being used in combination with jquery.mobile. $("#formName").validate({...}) is being called from $(document).on("pageinit",...) whereas the dynamic fields are added on the click of a button. Don't know if that matters?

Comment: Please edit your OP to include that info.

Comment: @Sparky: you are right, fixed in issue #670. I have replicated that fix into my copy until such time as a new version is officially released. Also fixed in issue #674, but I do not know which version will make it to release. Missing code in normalizeRules between versions 10 and 11 identified in #674 (restoring this missing code fixes the problem too), but funnily enough the fix suggested in #674 is not to restore the code and also differs from #670.

Comment: I'm not so sure that this is a bug... you can see my jsFiddle below is working fine with jQ Mobile.

Answer (score 36):

Your code seems to be working, without error, as you posted it.

**DEMO with DOM ready:  http://jsfiddle.net/UZTnE/**

**DEMO with PageInit & jQuery Mobile:  http://jsfiddle.net/xJ3E2/**

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            field1: {
                required: "Enter something"
            }
        }
    });

    $('[name*="field"]').each(function () {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "Enter something else"
            }
        });
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**BTW**:

this...

```
ignore: null, // include hidden fields
```

should be...

```
ignore: [], // include hidden fields
```

See:  [jQuery Validate - Enable validation for hidden fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466643/jquery-validate-enable-validation-for-hidden-fields/8565769#8565769)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on ignore:[]; still not sure about the original problem though; I have compared the jquery.validate.min I have with the version on the asp.net cdn and they are identical. I will look into this more tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: @MartinRobins, just open http://jsfiddle.net/xJ3E2/show/ in your browser and "view source".  Compare it to your code.

Comment: I have updated to reflect my code. DOM version (http://jsfiddle.net/UZTnE/2/) no longer works; Cannot get JQM version to run at all. Different problem though.

Comment: @MartinRobins:  Because you broke it.  You are trying to select `$("#field2")` where one does not exist.  `#field2` is looking for `id="field2"`, **not** `name="field2"`.  Try this one:  http://jsfiddle.net/UZTnE/3/

Comment: I can see what you mean; I was simply trying to update the code to represent what I am trying to achieve and did not notice that you had not provided id's in you example. I will try and find time to provide a proper update that shows the real error, but as I originally stated I am not the only person to report this and multiple fix attempts have already been made to the github source - one of which when applied to the latest release copy resolves my problem.

Comment: @MartinRobins, yes, without a doubt, there were/are issues with the plugin when using the `rules('add')` method with the `messages` option. However, these bugs are not present as you originally posted your code here in your OP... and that's all I can say.  I wish you luck.

Comment: Just upgraded to 1.11.1 which fixed the problem with the complaining of the messages in custom rules('add'), but the onclick: false to prevent auto-validation on click is not working for these custom methods.

Comment: @bcm, if you read the documentation, you'll notice that `onclick: false` is only for disabling the validation test when clicking on `radio` and `checkbox` inputs.

Comment: Fantastic, this helped me a bunch.

Comment: How can I make this work with a custom rule? The custom rule doesn't execute

Answer (score 11):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#controlId").rules("add", {
     required : true,
     messages : { required : 'field is required.' }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as an answer to this old issue, I do like this to get the meassges inside the rules object.

After you have added the rules you can add messages like this:

```
var inputRules = $('input').rules();
inputRules.messages = {required: 'your message'};
```

[image]

Good luck!