# jQuery Validate passes with only 1 field passing validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Not entirely sure and cannot find a setting to allow 1 of x number of validations to pass validation on an entire form.

I've had to use the .rules("add" function as my fields have array keys in the name attribute. 
jQuery Validate works as expected when all fields fail but if 1 field has valid content, the whole form passes validation.

```
<form id="new_user_session">
   <input class="input-block-level sq-input" id="user_session_email" name="user_session[email]" placeholder="email address" type="text">
   <input class="input-block-level sq-input" id="user_session_password" name="user_session[password]" placeholder="password" type="password">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function() {
      jQuery('#new_user_session').validate();

      jQuery("#user_session_email").rules("add", {
          email: true,
          messages: {
              email: "Please insert a valid email address",
              required: "Please insert your email address"
          },
          required: true
      });

      jQuery("#user_session_password").rules("add", {
          messages: {
              required: "Please insert your password"
          },
          required: true
      });
  });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: is there any error in the console

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D63Hf/ is giving an error

Comment: @ArunPJohny the error disappears when you do not use the messages anymore: http://jsfiddle.net/D63Hf/1/

Comment: @AndreasSchwarz yes but it looks like a bug in the plugin itself

Comment: this question is on same problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/15482523/678338

Comment: Yes, it's [a documented bug](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/674) in the plugin.  However, there is no good reason for the OP to be using `rules('add')` in the first place.  See:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use the `rules('add')` method in the first place, so you can easily avoid [the bug](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/674) entirely.

Simply follow the [documented guidelines for `names` that contain brackets](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29) and surround them in quotes.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/K65e5/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#new_user_session').validate({
        rules: {
            'user_session[email]': {
                email: true,
                required: true
            },
            'user_session[password]': {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'user_session[email]': {
                email: "Please insert a valid email address",
                required: "Please insert your email address"
            },
            'user_session[password]': {
                required: "Please insert your password"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I thought I tried quotes around the names of the fields and it failed. But, tried it again and it worked as expected. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

After some searching, it seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/674) with the last version of the validate plugin. It happens when you use the `messages` property when adding a rule.

You have two immediate solutions to this problem:

- Remove your custom messages
- Download the [previous version](http://bassistance.de/2012/09/07/release-validation-plugin-1-10-0/) of the plugin

**EDIT:** The author fixed the problem with [this commit](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/commit/4a134b6db6db169dd272cfa7ad4e7c8782b7a39e), so you can add a third solution:

- Download [the source](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation) from Github

Comment: Thanks for your investigation ! I'll keep an eye out for the next stable release.