# JQuery Validate dynamically change ignore rule

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I have a simple validate block like this:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
     ignore: ":hidden"
});
```

When the user clicks a certain button, I would like to change that ignore rule to `ignore: []` , then validate it and then switch back. I realize I could use classes instead but I want to know if there is a way around that.

Edit:
It should be noted that `ignore: []` is the proper way to do it when using `.validate()`.

Comment: Also see this answer for proper implementation of `ignore: ''`:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$('#myForm').validate().settings.ignore = "newIgnore";
```

The validate() method returns you a reference to the validator object you created with your original validate() call.

You can then call the property .settings.ignore

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I wasn't able to find this myself.

Comment: @Falantar014 Probably because it's a needle in a haystack. I've just tried 50 different things that you'd expect to reset or "forget" the old ignore setting (including your extremely reasonable approach put forward in the question) . But nope, only this.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing after I found out `validate()` caches the validator the first time it's created and then ignores any new options passed to it in successive calls.