# jquery validate span element

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I know that jquery validate is designed to check form fields but is it possible to check if a span class contains a value?

For example a select box appends a selected value automatically to  
(For the moment this way cannot be changed)

Is there any chance to validate the span class?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: why do you need to validate whatever isn't a user input?

Comment: a user selects options from a dropdown selectbox, and this value is appended to span

Comment: Why can't you just validate the value of the select box?

Comment: I don't really get what you want to do ... Waybe this can help you : http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: Why not use a multiple select box? Or append a hidden `input`? Lots of workarounds here.

Comment: @ChristophHa and.... where's user input in a span? You can just validate select box

Comment: I know it is hard to understand, I did not know either why it is build this way.
but the drop down got a span class which customized for user expericene
therefore the selected options from the drop down are appended to span and the input select is always hidden

Comment: Create a concise example and show the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"I know that jQuery Validate is designed to check form fields but is it possible to check if a span class contains a value?"*

No, this is not a feature of the plugin.

1. Elements to be validated must be contained within a set of `<form></form>` tags.
2. Only `<select>` and the various types of `<input>` elements can be validated.

See documentation:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Any "workaround" is going to have to follow the two points above.  By setting the `ignore` option to `[]`, [you can validate hidden fields as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235).

Answer (score 2):

You could add a hidden input related to the span and validate that control instead. If you follow this approach, you'll need to clear the `ignore` pattern to include hidden elements.