# Adding jquery validation to Chosen drop down list on post in ASP.NET MVC page

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a default site template from Visual Studio 2013 preview which integrates Bootstrap by default (which I replaced with v3)

In a form, the Jquery validate on POST correctly highlights error fields, except for drop down boxes that I've styled with the Chosen plugin.

[image]

My code for the drop down list in question is:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Job.State,
    Model.States,
    "Select a State", new { @class = "form-control chosen-select"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Job.State)
```

This renders as follows:

```
<select class="input-validation-error form-control chosen-select" id="Job_State" name="Job.State" style="width: 50%; display: none;">
    <option value="">Select a State</option>
    <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
    <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
    <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
    <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
    <option value="NT">NT</option>
    <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
    <option value="WA">WA</option>
</select>
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" style="width: 135px;" title="" id="Job_State_chosen"><a class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1"><span>Select a State</span><div><b></b></div>
</a>
    <div class="chosen-drop">
        <div class="chosen-search">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off"></div>
        <ul class="chosen-results">
            <li class="active-result result-selected" style="" data-option-array-index="0">Select a State</li>
            <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">ACT</li>
            <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="2">NSW</li>
            <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="3">QLD</li>
            <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="4">TAS</li>
            <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="5">NT</li>
            <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="6">VIC</li>
            <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="7">WA</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<span class="field-validation-error">State is required.</span>
```

Notice that the input-validation-error class is being added to an element that Chosen sets to display:none so obviously the border doesn't get shown.

Ideally if I can add the input-validation-error class to the div that's within the select, then this will fix my problem, but I don't know how to do that, so any assistance would be greatly welcome!

Note - I'm actually not after client side validation, I'm only using validation on POST.

Comment: Are you using jQuery Validate for your client validation?

Comment: Yes, the one that comes as part of the default templates, think it's jquery.validate and jquery.validate.obtrusive

Comment: If any of the answers provided helped you then you might want to mark them as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bartek Marnane, You're going to need to [override the highlight and unhighlight](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) callbacks that jQuery Validate uses by default when applying it's failed validation css class.  What you'll want to do is inspect the element on highlight and unhighlight to see if it's a chosen drop down list to apply/remove the css class from the element that is presenting the list.

I haven't verified the highlight and unhighlight function for chosen because I've not worked with that plugin before.  If anything you'll end up tweaking my css class check on the element to see if it is a chosen drop down or not.  Realize that the element that will fire validation will be the one that is not visible.  If it's not firing validation then there is a setting in jQuery validate to [ignore certain elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466643/jquery-validate-enable-validation-for-hidden-fields/14574974#14574974).

```
// This script block should be placed after jQuery, jQuery Validate and jQuery Validate
// Unobtrusive plugins have been loaded.
$(function () {
    // retrieves the current jQuery validator for the form
    var $validator = $("form").validate();
    // We're going to override the default highlight method from jQuery when applying
    // our css class for an error
    $validator.settings.highlight = function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        var $element = $(element);
        if ($element.hasClass("chosen-select")) {
            // It's a chosen element so move to the next element in the DOM 
            // which should be your container for chosen.  Add the error class to 
            // that instead of the hidden select
            $element.next().addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        }
        else if (element.type === "radio") {
            this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        } else {
            $element.addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        }
    };
    // We're going to override the default unhighlight method from jQuery when removing
    // our css class for an error
    $validator.settings.unhighlight = function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        var $element = $(element);
        if ($element.hasClass("chosen-select")) {
            // It's a chosen element so move to the next element in the DOM 
            // which should be your container for chosen.  Add the error class to 
            // that instead of the hidden select
            $element.next().removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        }
        else if (element.type === "radio") {
            this.findByName(element.name).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        } else {
            $element.removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Hi, I got this working thanks to this answer, but in the end ending up ditching it and changing to Select2 - which doesn't have the same issue.

Comment: @Evonet,Could you please show the working code.. I'm facing the same pbm with @html.DropdownlistFor() in mvc4  Or could you pleas check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950610/not-getting-validation-message-for-html-dropdownlistfor-once-chosen-jquery-is

Answer (score 0):

I have never used chosen but I think you might be able to set the input-validation-error class in your view by checking the ModelState:

```
@if(!ModelState.IsValid){
    Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.Job.State,
        Model.States,
        "Select a State", new { @class = "input-validation-error form-control chosen-select"})
        Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Job.State)
}
```