# Validation does not apply to dropdowns in mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

Note the following code.
My problem is that since upgrading mvc4 to mvc5, dropdown validation is not done correctly. In the code below, although I've set in the model dropdown is mandatory, but if the user does not select it, it will not give any errors to the user and will save the amount in the database zero.

dropdowns have been styled with chosen-jquery

My Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
public int PaymentTypeID { get; set; }
```

My Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PaymentTypeID, new { @class = "control-lable" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PaymentTypeID, (SelectList)(ViewData["PaymentTypelist"]), "Choose..", new { @class = "form-control chosen-select" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PaymentTypeID)
        </div>
</div>

    <script src="/Scripts/Menu/html5shiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/Menu/actions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/Menu/jquery.cookies.2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script src="/Scripts/fontawesome-all.js"></script>


    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.0.6-development-only.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/enquire.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.pnotify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script src="/Scripts/placeholdr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/respond.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script src="/Scripts/knockout-3.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/attachfiles.js"></script>


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you've styled drop-downs with Chosen, then the element being validated is hidden.  By default hidden elements are not validated.  You will have to change the jQuery Validate settings to include `ignore: []`, which means ignore nothing, validate everything including the hidden elements.

Comment: See:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/18613802/594235

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding jquery validation to Chosen drop down list on post in ASP.NET MVC page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613802/adding-jquery-validation-to-chosen-drop-down-list-on-post-in-asp-net-mvc-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RequiredAttribute` attribute specifies that when a field on a form is validated, the field must contain a value. A validation exception is raised if the property is `null`, contains an empty string (""), or contains only white-space characters.

So `[Required]` only works for nullable type. Try using `Nullable<int>` or `int?` instead of `int`.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
public int? PaymentTypeID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use the above nullable type by @Mannan Bahelim then you can go for this Range Attribute what it does is allowing only integers greater than zero.

```
 [Range(1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "*")]
```