# select2 scroll to error not working with jquery validation and asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation, jquery-select2

Posting this here in case someone else has the same problem...

When using a `select2` dropdown in a C# MVC4 site, the page is not scrolled to the correct position when validation fails. Validation as such works and error scrolling also works for other controls, just not `select2`'s. The reason AFAICS is that `select2` replaces the original `select` with it's own markup and then set the original select as `display:none`. jquery.validate then has no valid target to scroll to.

We are using twitter bootstrap for styling, but I don't think it has any impact on this problem.

Comment: Yes, the jQuery Validate plugin will ignore hidden elements by default.  The fix is to simply set the `ignore` option to `[]`, which disables this default behavior.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235

Comment: True but the hidden element is still not the one we want to scroll to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jquery.validate documentation (as well as many answers here on StackOverflow) suggests that you use $.validator.setDefaults to assign the invalidHandler, but I couldn't get this to work in asp.net (it does work for focusInvalid however), probably due to us using the MS unobtrusive library. Instead I used this code in my jquery ready handler:

```
    $(function() {
        $.validator.setDefaults({         
            focusInvalid: false
        });

        function scrollToError(error, validator) {
            var elem = $(validator.errorList[0].element);
            if (elem.length) {
                if (elem.is(':visible'))
                    return elem.offset().top - 16;
                elem = elem.prev($(".select2-container"));
                if (elem.length) {
                    return elem.offset().top - 16;
                }
            }
            return 0; // scroll to top if all else fails
        }

        $('form').bind('invalid-form.validate', function(error, validator) {
            // fix scrolling and validation for select2

            if (!validator.numberOfInvalids())
                return;

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: scrollToError(error, validator)
            }, 500);
        });
...
```

I set `focusInvalid` to false to disable and avoid conflict with the standard scroll and focus behavior.

The `bind()` call is used instead of the invalidHandler option and is the same as used by the validate plugin.

`scrollToError()` selects the first invalid element and returns the position to scroll to, either a normal visible element or a previous item with the 'select2-container' class (i.e a select2 element) or top of page if all else fails.

Standard behavior (showing validation errors etc) still works as before.

Hope this helps someone and if you have a better solution I would be very interested in knowing about it.

Comment: Perfect solution peter3! Still valid in 2022! This is the answer to smooth scrolling to any invalid field including both inputs and selects. Just update the elem.offset().top - ?? to whatever value you want so the first invalid field scrolls into view and well below the top menu bar.

Comment: Ha! I don't know any other answer I've ever provided that is still valid almost 9 years later! :D