# exclude ignore based on some other element visibility jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am currently working on a project what has the following code

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        ....
        'final_input': {
            require:true
        }
    },
    ignore: ':hidden'
});
```

I have a custom dropdown list plugin which will be generated based on a hidden input. the code will look like

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<div id="dropdownlist" style="display: none">
    <div class="option"></div>
    <div class="option"></div>
    <div class="option"></div>
    <input id="final_input" name="final_input" type="text" style="display: none" />
</div>
```

the dropdownlist is also hidden until checkbox is checked. currently, it will ignore all hidden elements.  so my final_input will not be validated. if I put something in ignore like :hidden:not('#final_input'). it will validate it no matter what. however I only want to validate it when the dropdownlist is visible. does anyone know how I can exclude the final_input from the ignore only when the dropdownlist in visible? or the checkbox is checked?

Comment: Could your `ignore` object contain a function that returns the proper selector based on what is visible in the form?

Answer (score 1):

Rather that messing around with including/excluding hidden input elements, use the `depends` method to make the `required` rule depend on something else.

For simplicity of demonstration, my example does not use a custom drop-down, however, you can use one and my approach will work the same.  [To disable the ignoring of all hidden fields, use `ignore: []`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235).

In this basic demo, the text field is only `required` when the checkbox is ticked or the drop-down is visible.

```
    ignore: [], // <-- do not ignore any hidden fields
    rules: {
        final_input: {
            required: {
                depends: function () {
                    return ( $('#dropdownlist').is(':visible') || $('#check').is(':checked') );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**DEMO (invisible select):  http://jsfiddle.net/AZYpf/**

**Same DEMO (visible select):  http://jsfiddle.net/AZYpf/1/**

Custom selectors:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/selectors/