# Validate separated tabs Jquery Validator plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the next Jquery Validator script;

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("letras", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z ñÑáéíóúüç]+$/);
}, "Only letters.");

$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#inscripcion').validate({

                errorClass: 'form-control-error',
                validClass: 'form-control-sucess',
                ignore: "",

                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    if ($("#inscripcion").validate() == true) {
                        alert("Form not completed");
                    } else {
                        form.submit();
                    }
                },

                rules: {

                    nombrer: {
                        minlength: 2,
                        letras: true,
                        required: true
                    },
                    apellidor: {
                        minlength: 2,
                        required: true
                    },
                    cedular: {
                        minlength: 7,
                        number: true,
                        required: true
                    },

                    highlight: function (element) {
                        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
                    },

                    success: function (element) {
                        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');

                    }
                });
        }); // end document.ready

    $('#menu a[href="#estudiante"]').click(function (event) {
        var estado = $('#inscripcion').valid();
        if (estado == false) {
            alert("You miss some data please complete it");
        }
    });

    $('#botonestu').click(function (event) {
        var estado = $('#inscripcion').valid();
        if (estado == false) {
            alert("You miss some data please complete it");
        }
    });
```

The problem is that if I use 'ignore: "",' the events that I made for when someone clicks a tab or a button activates even if the especified tab is full. But if i removeit somebody could click the submit button directly and it would submit the entire form even if it's complety empty. And also the "alert" in submitHandler its not working even tho the form.submit() is.

Comment: Show enough HTML to construct a concise example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    if ($("#inscripcion").validate() == true) {
        alert("Form not completed");
    } else {
        form.submit();
    }
},
```

- `$("#inscripcion").validate()` is totally meaningless in this context.  `.validate()` is only the *initialization* method of the plugin, **not** the *testing* method.  Calling `.validate()` more than once will do nothing.
- As per the documentation, **the `submitHandler` only fires upon the click of the submit button *when the form is valid*.**  This means that testing for validity within the `submitHandler` is superfluous.  In other words, this test inside the `submitHandler` is meaningless because whenever your `if valid` statement is evaluated, the form **is** already always valid.
- If all you want to do is a `form.submit()`, then the entire `submitHandler` callback option needs to be removed.  This is the default behavior of the plugin that you do not need to over-ride.  Typically the `submitHandler` callback is used when you want to submit the form data with `.ajax()` and/or perform other actions when a form is valid.

---

I am not sure what you want to achieve with `ignore: ""`, however, if you're trying to [enable validation of hidden fields, use `ignore: []`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235).  Otherwise, if you want hidden fields ignored for validation, remove the `ignore` option entirely, because this is already the default behavior of the plugin.

---

You've also **incorrectly** placed `highlight` and `success` inside of `rules` as well as a missing closing brace on `rules`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#inscripcion').validate({
        // your other options,
        rules: {
            nombrer: {
                ...
            },
            ....
            highlight: function (element) { // <- incorrectly placed inside "rules" option
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
            },
            success: function (element) {  // <- incorrectly placed inside "rules" option
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');

            }
        // <- missing a closing brace "}" here
    });

}); // end document.ready
```

**Here is the working version of your code:  http://jsfiddle.net/yyxLs/**

Comment: Thanks I just checked my code and fix those missing braces and it worked!