# jquery tokeninput with jquery validate required

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-tokeninput

I have a form (ASP.NET MVC) with two tokeninput textboxes.  I also use `jquery.validate()` function to validate that both of those fields are required.

My problem is, the required rule is not working on the **first** of the two tokeninput fields (It doesn't matter which one it is; I tested flipping the two fields.).

I made sure to set `ignore = ''` to allow for hidden fields, since the tokeninput basically changes the field to an unordered list and a hidden input field.

It's really strange, but I really want to require both of those fields. 
Any ideas?

Here's my code:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<form id="SendPOSettingsForm" method="post" name="SendPOInfo" action="/po/SendPOToVendor/">
  <div>
    <table cellpadding="2">
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="sendviagroup" name="sendViaEmail" id="sendViaEmail" value="Y" @emailChecked /> <b>Email To:</b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="sendPOEmailTo" id="sendPOEmailTo" style="font-family: arial; font-size:11px;"  />
          <input type="hidden" name="sendPOEmailTo_List" id="sendPOEmailTo_List" value="@emailTo" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="sendviagroup" name="sendViaFax" id="sendViaFax" value="Y" onchange="UpdateAttnVisibility(this.checked);" @faxChecked /> <b>Fax To:</b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="sendPOFaxTo" id="sendPOFaxTo" style="font-family: arial; font-size:11px;" />
          <input type="hidden" name="sendPOFaxTo_List" id="sendPOFaxTo_List"  value="@faxTo" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Subject:</b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="sendSubject" name="sendSubject" style="font-family: arial; font-size:11px; width:600px; height:25px;" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><b>Message:</b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td><textarea rows="10" cols="60" id="sendBody" name="sendBody" style="font-family: arial; font-size:11px;"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="bSendPO" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;Send&nbsp;&nbsp;" class="orangeButton2" style="font-weight:bold;" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;Cancel&nbsp;&nbsp;" onclick="CancelSendPO();" class="orangeButton2" style="font-weight:bold;" />
    <ul class="errorclass" id="errorsummary"></ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

**SCRIPT CODE:**

```
$("#sendPOEmailTo").tokenInput("/Admin/Cron/GetVendorContactEmails.aspx?v=" + vendorNo, {
  theme: "facebook",
  preventDuplicates: true,
  allowFreeTagging: true
});

$("#sendPOFaxTo").tokenInput("/Admin/Cron/GetVendorContactFaxes.aspx?v=" + vendorNo, {
  theme: "facebook",
  preventDuplicates: true,
  allowFreeTagging: true
});

var formValidator = $("#SendPOSettingsForm").validate({
  ignore: "",
  rules: {
    sendPOFaxTo: {
      required: "#sendViaFax:checked" //only required if sendViaFax is checked
    },
    sendPOEmailTo: {
      required: "#sendViaEmail:checked" //only required if sendViaEmail is checked
    },
    sendSubject: {
      required: true
    },
    sendViaEmail: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".sendviagroup"]
    },
    sendViaFax: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".sendviagroup"]
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function (form) {
    //alert("is successful, no problems");
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

When I test this, checking the "FAX" checkbox but leaving the "FAX TO" textbox blank works.  This gives me an error message.  HOWEVER, checking the "EMAIL" checkbox but leaving the "EMAIL TO" textbox blank submits the form without giving me an error!
If I change the order of the HTML & put the two fax inputs before the email inputs, then the FAX TO (`sendPOFaxTo`) required rule breaks, and EMAIL (`sendPOEmailTo`) required rule works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `required: $('#sendViaFax')[0].checked`

Comment: Which version of jQuery Validate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"If I change the order of the HTML & put the two fax inputs before the email inputs, then the FAX TO (`sendPOFaxTo`) required rule breaks, and EMAIL (`sendPOEmailTo`) required rule works."*

You are describing the symptoms of a known bug/issue with the `require_from_group` method that caused certain other inputs on the page to be ignored, depending on their placement.

The fix is to make sure you're using the latest versions of the jQuery Validation plugin and its `additional-methods.js` file, which is 1.11.1.

---

Also, the proper way to disable the `ignore` option is, not to set it to `''` but, to set it to `[]` instead.  See this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235

```
ignore: []
```

Comment: I am using 1.11.1 of the validation & additional methods.  However, i'm using a fairly old version of jquery.  (Any time I try to update it, various datatables features mess up, so I've kept it to jquery-1.6.2.

Comment: Also, I've tried ignore: [].  And, I've tried putting the ignore on the validator object.  Let me try taking out require_from_group and see if it works.  (I was so sure it was the tokeninput causing the problem.)  If taking out require_from_group makes it work, maybe i can do a basic dependency on the two checkboxes, requiring it if the other is NOT checked.  let me try that.  i'll get back to you in a minute.

Comment: AWESOME!! You're amazing!!! Yep, taking out the required_from_group worked.   Instead, I used "required: depends" as follows:

Comment: oops, i pressed enter before putting in the code: <br/> <br/>sendViaEmail: {
                    //required: [1, ".sendviagroup"]
                    required: {
                        depends: function(element) {
                            if ($('#sendViaFax').is(':checked')){
                                return false;
                            }
                            else{
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }