# JQuery validate ignore [] and more

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need to validate hidden fields, so I have this below ([validate hidden fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466643/jquery-validate-enable-validation-for-hidden-fields))

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: [] });
```

I would like to ignore a certain class as well, but I'm not sure of the syntax to get both.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: "[], .ignoreThisClass" });
```

This obviously does not work but how can I specify to both validate hidden and ignore my class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add your class to the array instead.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: [".ignoreThisClass"] });
```

It's an array of jquery selectors. If the element matches the selector, it is ignored. By default it is `[":hidden"]` which is why making it `[]` makes it allow hidden elements.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
ignore: ".ignoreThisClass"
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting in your `.ignoreThisClass` class the property.

```
visibility: hidden;
```

I believe it will work