# jquery validation dependent on specific radio button being selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am pulling my hair out.  For all intents and purposes I think this should work.  I only want to validate that a hidden field has a value if certain radio buttons are selected.

Here's what I've got:

```
$("#myform").validate({
        ignore: "",
        rules: {
            MaritalStatusDate: {
                required: {
                    depends: function () {
                        return $("input[type='radio'].maritalStatusRadio:checked").val() != '1';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            MaritalStatusDate: {
                required: "You must enter a marital status date"
            }
        }
    });
```

MaritalStatusDate is the name/id of my hidden field.  I've tried about 100 different iterations of this code, and the form gets submitted everytime.

any ideas?

edit: adding html.

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

        <form action="/cont/meth" id="myform" method="post"> 
        <input class="maritalStatusRadio" data-val="true" data-val-required="The MaritalStatusAnswer field is required." id="maritalStatus_1" name="MaritalStatusAnswer" type="radio" value="1" />
        <input class="maritalStatusRadio" id="maritalStatus_2" name="MaritalStatusAnswer" type="radio" value="2" />
        <input class="maritalStatusRadio" id="maritalStatus_3" name="MaritalStatusAnswer" type="radio" value="3" />
        <input class="maritalStatusRadio" id="maritalStatus_4" name="MaritalStatusAnswer" type="radio" value="4" />
        <input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field MaritalStatusDate must be a date." id="MaritalStatusDate" name="MaritalStatusDate" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="go" />
        </form>
```

Comment: Include the relevant HTML markup!

Comment: Should be `ignore: []` if you want to ignore nothing.

Comment: `= "1"` why put a number into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without showing your HTML markup, I'm just guessing this is how it looks…

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="hidden" name="MaritalStatusDate" />
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="1" class="maritalStatusRadio" />
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="0" class="maritalStatusRadio" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

In that case, this works...

```
depends:  function(element) {
    return !($("input[type='radio'].maritalStatusRadio[value='1']").is(":checked"));
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/nVc2N/**

---

Side-note:  It really should be `ignore: []` if you want to ignore nothing.

See:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235

Comment: ya your jsfiddle does indeed work, but it's still not flying on my solution.  I've added my html.  Can you see any issues with it?  I also updated the depends function to what you have.

Comment: ya you're right again.  What else could be tripping this up on my end?  I've added my script references to my OP in the HTML section.

Comment: for whatever reason, when I pulled the validate method out of document.ready, it worked.  thanks for your help.

Comment: @ChristopherJohnson, I'm glad it worked, but FYI, that makes absolutely no sense, unless your DOM ready event handler never fires.