# validate date has been picked using hidden field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Im using a datepicker within a form and submitting the form using jquery ajax post.

I have a hidden field RequiredDate, and setting that in the change event for the datepicker

Im then using that in the ajax post

```
 var requiredDate = $("#RequiredDate").val();
```

The html for my hiden field is:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select the required date" id="RequiredDate" name="RequiredDate" type="hidden" value="" />
```

Im allowing hidden field validation using:

```
 $.validator.setDefaults({
        ignore: "#InternalColourId, #ExternalColourId, #RequiredDate"
    });
```

I want to be able to validate that a date has been picked (ideally without the use of 3rd party plugins)

Can you help?

Comment: `ignore` means "ignore", not "allow".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the cleanest way, but this seems to work for me

```
  var isFormValid = form.valid();

        if (!$("#RequiredDate").val() > 0) {
            if (isFormValid)
            {
                $(".validation-summary-errors ul").empty();

            }
            if (!$(".date-invalid").length) {
                $(".validation-summary-errors ul").append("<li class='date-invalid'>Please Select required date</li>");
            }
            $(".validation-summary-errors").show();
            isFormValid = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP**:

> *"I'm **allowing** hidden field validation using:"*

```
ignore: "#InternalColourId, #ExternalColourId, #RequiredDate"
```

No, you're not.  You are doing the exact opposite of "allowing".

`ignore: "#RequiredDate"` means exactly what it says… this field **is *ignored*** during validation.

Since all hidden fields are ignored by default, you have to *disable* the `ignore` option like this…

```
ignore: []  // <- Set 'ignore' to nothing - allows validation of hidden fields
```

Alternatively, any other specific parameters inside `ignore` will also over-ride the default setting to ignore hidden fields.  In other words, if you set `ignore: ".ignore"`, then *only* fields with class `ignore` will be skipped.

See:  [jQuery Validate - Enable validation for hidden fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466643/jquery-validate-enable-validation-for-hidden-fields/8565769#8565769)