# jQuery selector for hidden elements except

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, tinymce

By default, [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) [ignores hidden elements](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore):

> ignore (default: ":hidden")
>
> Type: Selector
>
> Elements to ignore when
>   validating, simply filtering them out. jQuery’s not-method is used,
>   therefore everything that is accepted by not() can be passed as this
>   option. Inputs of type submit and reset are always ignored, so are
>   disabled elements.

Here's the relevant code from jquery.validate.js:

```
elements: function() {
    var validator = this,
        rulesCache = {};

    // select all valid inputs inside the form (no submit or reset buttons)
    return $( this.currentForm )
    .find( "input, select, textarea" )
    .not( ":submit, :reset, :image, [disabled]" )
    .not( this.settings.ignore )
    .filter( function() {
        // snip
    });
}
```

The problem I'm having is due to the fact that I'm also using TinyMCE. When TinyMCE is applied to a textarea, it hides the textarea and creates an iframe in its place. This means jQuery Validation ignores it by default.

I can force the validation to pickup the hidden textareas by changing the value of the ignore option to `null`:

```
$("#myform").validate({
    ignore: null
});
```

Unfortunately this creates a huge performance issue on my page which has hundreds of hidden input fields. It's so bad it actually crashes Chrome and IE (Firefox is a champ, but still slow).

I think what I need to solve this problem is a jQuery selector for hidden elements *except those with a certain class name*, or something like this:

```
$("#myform").validate({
    ignore: ':hidden(:not(textarea.tinymce))'
});
```

I realize this is an invalid selector. Is there a selector like this? If not, is there a better way that I'm not seeing to tell jQuery Validation to ignore all the hidden elements except those hidden by TinyMCE?

Comment: FWIW: [`ignore: []` to ignore "nothing", not `ignore: null`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466643/jquery-validate-enable-validation-for-hidden-fields/8565769#8565769).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Special selectors usually go after other selectors (except in the case of `not` and `is` and a couple others:

```
":hidden:not(textarea.tinymce)"
```