# jquery validate on @Html.DropDownListFor with bootstrap selectpicker

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a `form` where say I have 2 controls. A `select` control which has been customized using `bootstrap-selectpicker` and a `textbox` which are `strongly typed` with a `viewmodel`. Below are the details of the project structure and here is the **[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RbkJ2M)** and validation is using **[jquery-validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)**

**SampleViewModel.cs**

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please Select a Role")]
        //Not sure whether Required has to be assigned to RoleId or Roles
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public SelectList Roles { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please Enter a name")]
        public string name{get;set;}
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h1>Hello Stranger</h1>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, 
                             new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id="frmSample" }))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleId, Model.Roles, "Please Select your Country", new{@class="selectpicker"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.RoleId)
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name, null, new{@class="form-control"}) 
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.name)
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success submit">Ask</button>
            }
            <br/><br/>
        </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        SampleViewModel model=new SampleViewModel();
        model.Roles = new SelectList(new string[] { "Admin", "Manager" });
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    $("#frmSample").validate({
        onfocusout: true
    });
});
$('.submit').on('click',function(){
    if($("#frmSample").valid())
        alert(true);
});
```

**Problem**

- The problem I am facing is my `dropdown` element doesn't get
  validated using `jquery validation` whereas my `textbox` gets
  validated. May be the problem is the way I am initializing or
  assigning the `Required` attribute to the particular `model`
  attribute and I am not sure for which one to assign the `required`
  attribute.
- I have given `onfocusout:true` to validate on focus out but unless
  you type something on `textbox` and delete the content, the
  validation doesn't happen

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: `.selectpicker()` I assume is a jquery plugin, which will be hiding the `<select>` element and replacing it with its own html. You need to modify the validator to validate hidden inputs (by default they are not). And the `[Required]` attribute is correct on the `RoleId` property :)

Comment: Always with a good reply @StephenMuecke and I was expecting this.. :) But as per my research I need to set `ignore: []` on validation according to **[this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466643/jquery-validate-enable-validation-for-hidden-fields)** but still this isn't helpful.. :(

Comment: That should work fine, but your demo has `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Roles)` - it should be `RoleId`

Comment: I have [forked the fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qsUa7R) to show that it works :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke.. I have re-forked your fiddle and yea that was a good catch. But now I am facing different issue. Even though if you select a Role its giving a different error.. Here is the **[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9F6m4X)**. Any idea on this?

Comment: That's because property `RoleId` is type of `int` but you `SelectList` is generated from `List<string>` (an `int` cannot be bound to "Admin" or "Manager"). Either make it `string RoleId` or change the way you generate the `SelectList` (e.g. using the `Text` and `Value` properties of `SelectListItem`

Comment: Awesome.. :) Can you post this as answer please.. :) and also if possible both the approaches, [Text and Value].. :) plus any idea on 2nd problem? :) @StephenMuecke

Comment: Have updated the [fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qsUa7R). Need a short break so will add an answer a bit later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jquery plugin hides the `<select>` element that the `DropDownListFor()` method generates (`display:none;`) and adds its own html. By default hidden inputs are not validated by `jquery.validate.js` so you need to override this behavior using

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
  ignore: []
});
```

Note this will validate all hidden inputs so to just validate this one, you could use `ignore: ":hidden:not('#RoleId')"`

In addition, you have other errors. Your `RoleId` property is typeof `int` but your `SelectList` will generate options with values that are `strings` ("Admin" and "Manager") and cannot be bound to `int`. Either change the property to `string RoleId` or create a `SelectList` with values that are typeof `int`. For example if you have a `Roles` table with fields `int ID` and `string Name`, then

```
var roles = db.Roles();
model.Roles = new SelectList(roles, "ID", "Name");
```

or

```
model.Roles = roles.Select(r => new SelectListItem()
{
  Value = r.ID.ToString(),
  Text = r.Name
};
```

Refer [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qsUa7R)