# How to validate Kendo Dropdownlist using jQuery validate

Tags: kendo-ui, jquery-validate, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have normal razor as well as kendo controls in my form, i am facing some problem while trying to validate kendo dropdownlist using jquery validate plugin.
The below is my code.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
          .Name("color")
          .DataTextField("Text")
          .DataValueField("Value")
          .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
             new SelectListItem() {
                  Text = "Select Value",
                  Value = ""
              }, new SelectListItem() {
                  Text = "Black",
                  Value = "2"
              },
              new SelectListItem() {
                  Text = "Orange",
                  Value = "3"
              },
              new SelectListItem() {
                  Text = "Grey",
                  Value = "4"
              }
          }).Value("")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
    )
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

now i have used my jquery validate like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dropDownForm").validate({
            rules: {
                color: "required"
            },
            highlight: function (element) {
                alert('highlight');
            },
            unhighlight: function (element) {
                alert('unhighlight');
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                return false;
            },
            debug: true
        });
    });
```

but i am not able to validate the dropdown list and both highlight and unhighlight event of jquery validate plugin is not getting called.
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Why can't use Kendo validator since you are already using Kendo UI : http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/validator/index

Comment: @Vijai the reason i dont want to use kendo validator is because i have many controls which are razor controls and i have a requirement in my project to use only kendo controls for dropdown and kendo draggable...
could you help me on how to validate kendo dropdown with jQuery validator as i have clearly suggested in my question above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is recommended

```
Put $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: '' }); not inside $(document).ready
```

[jQuery Validate - Enable validation for hidden fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466643/jquery-validate-enable-validation-for-hidden-fields/8565769#8565769)

http://www.telerik.com/forums/mvc-client-validation-not-working

Comment: This will break forms with hidden inputs. Instead, use `$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(span.k-dropdown:visible > input)" });` to only ignore hidden inputs, that are not part of a still visible kendo dropdown.