# bootstrap-combobox (by Daniel Farrel) and jquery-validaiton-plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

Has anyone made the jquery.validate plugin working with the bootstrap-combobox created by Daniel Farrel ?

The jquery.validate plugin works pretty well with the remaining bootstrap elements, but can't get it working with the bootstrap-combobox.

Here is the html :

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label for="categoryParent" class="control-label">Category</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <select id="categoryParent" name="categoryParent" class="combobox form-control">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select the category</option>
<option>...</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and the js :

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.row').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.row').removeClass('has-error');
        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    });

    $("#addProductForm").validate({
        rules: {
            categoryParent: {required: true}
        },
        messages: {                
            categoryParent : "Category required"

        },
        invalidHandler: function() {
            $("#cc-alert").css("display","block");
        },
        submitHandler: function() {

    //
    // more code
    //


            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap ComboBox hides the original `select` and replaces it with something more visually appealing.  However, the jQuery Validate plugin can only validate the original `select` element, but will also ignore it because it is hidden.

You simply have to use [the `ignore` option](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore) to tell it to [validate hidden elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235).

```
ignore: []  // ignore nothing, validate everything
```

In your code:

```
$("#addProductForm").validate({
    ignore: [],
    rules: { ....
```

OR:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: [],
    highlight: function(element) { ....
```

Comment: It worked at the first attempt! Thanks a lot, you saved my day.

Comment: any idea how can i remove the "errorClass"  :) ? it remains there once the field (combobox) is validated. Whereas it hides correctly with the other fields.

Comment: @user1611183, the classes are added/removed using the `highlight` and `unhighlight` options.  You'll have to customize these functions for your ComboBox element.