# How to use jQuery Validate plugin for bootstrap-select?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I am using **jQuery Validate** plugin ( [jqueryvalidation.org](http://jqueryvalidation.org) ) and trying to validate dropdown. The problem is that my dropdown use `bootstrap-select` plugin and that means library converts "normal" dropdown into `div` (for styling, live-search etc.) more info about `boostrap-select` - https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/.

My question is how can I use jQuery Validator plugin options on this `boostrap-select` dropdown.

Here is my code

```
echo $this->Form->input('customer_number', [
 'options' => $customer_number_list,
 'id' => 'customer_number',
 'class' => 'selectpicker',
 'empty' => __('All'),
 'label' => __('Customer number'),
 'value' => $this->request->data['customer_number'] ?? '',
 'onchange' => 'getDestinationList()'
]);
```

And below is jQuery Validator configuration (rules and messages)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#change_destination').validate({
      rules: {
        customer_number: {
          required: true
        }
      },
      messages: {
        customer_number: {
          required: 'Please select a template'
        }
      },
      submitHandler: function(form) { // blocks submission for demo
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

This code works if I change my dropdown class in form-control (but then my dropdown doesnt have "nice" look and other features what I am getting from bootstrap selectpicker library. Here is an example of Bootstrap dropdown library (https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/)

Thank you

Comment: Your actual dropdown probably exists somewhere in the DOM, but is likely hidden with CSS. Find that hidden element, figure out the selector (devtools will help with that) and try validating against it.

Comment: You have right, real select element exists in body and it is hidden, but jQuery Validator plugin doesnt generate "error" message because if you select something from dropdown - selected tag doesnt appear in real select element, it shows up only in that div list from bootstrap-select...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is that select option is hidden and in jQuery validator configuration is written - ignore hidden elements so you have to change jQuery Validation library configuration file:

```
ignore: ":hidden"
```

into

```
ignore: ""
```

You can find this options from line 255 - 265 based on jQuery library version. More info about the same problem you can find on GitHub bootstrap-select issues -> https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/215

I hope so that this works for you!

Comment: thank you, its working now!

Comment: [Actually, the proper format should be `ignore: []`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235)

Comment: @Sparky its the same answer from JohnWayne...

Comment: I don't know what that comment is supposed to mean.  I'm just telling you what the author of the plugin officially recommends when using this option.