# jquery- How to validate a signature input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that requires user to enter their digital signature before signing up. It looks like below:

[image]

So prior to signing up, user MUST enter their signature on the canvas box provided. I use jquery validation to validate my other fields before coming to this final page for signature.

I can validate all the fields except for the signature field. Any idea what I can do?

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 pl-3 pr-3 pt-2 mb-0">
    <canvas class="display-block signature-pad" style="touch-action: none;"></canvas>
    <p id="signatureError" name="signatureError" style="color: red; display: none;">Please provide your signature.</p>
    <div class="p-1 text-right">
      <button id="resetSignature" class="btn btn-sm" style="background-color: lightblue;">Reset</button>
      <button id="saveSignature" class="btn btn-sm" style="background-color: #fbcc34;">Save</button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" id="signatureInput">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 mb-0 pt-2">
    <div class="text-right">
      <input type="hidden" name="registrationFor" value="customer">
      <button type="submit" id="submit" class=" btn next-button bjsh-btn-gradient text-right">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
 var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    const signatureSaveButton = document.getElementById("saveSignature");
    const signatureResetButton = document.getElementById("resetSignature");
    const signatureError = document.getElementById("signatureError");
    const signatureInput = document.getElementById("signatureInput");

    // Initialize a new signaturePad instance.
    var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);

    // Clear signature pad.
    signatureResetButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      signaturePad.clear();
    });

    // Save signature pad as data url.
    signatureSaveButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
        signatureError.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        signatureUrl = signaturePad.toDataURL();
        signatureInput.value = signatureUrl;
      }
    });

    // Validate registration tab before moving to the next tab
    $("#register-form").validate({
      rules: {
        email: {
          required: true,
          // Specify that email should be validated
          // by the built-in "email" rule
          email: true
        },
        password: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 8,
        },
        password_confirmation: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 8,
          equalTo: "#password"
        },
        full_name: {
          required: true
        },
        nric: {
          required: true
        },
        address_1: {
          required: true
        },
        address_2: {
          required: true
        },
        address_3: {
          required: true
        },
        postcode: {
          required: true
        },
        city: {
          required: true
        },
        state: {
          required: true
        },
        contact_number_home: {
          required: true
        },
        contact_number_mobile: {
          required: true
        },
        existing_customer: {
          required: true
        },
        signatureError: {
          required: true
        },
      },
      messages: {
        email: {
          required: "Please enter an email",
          email: "The email is not valid"
        },
        password: {
          required: "Please enter a password",
          minlength: "Password must be minimum of 8 characters"
        },
        password_confirmation: {
          required: "Please confirm your password",
          minlength: "Passmust must be minimum of 8 characters",
          equalTo: "Password must be same as above"
        },
        full_name: {
          required: "Please enter your full name"
        },
        nric: {
          required: "Please enter your identity card number"
        },
        address_1: {
          required: "Please enter your address"
        },
        address_2: {
          required: "Please enter your address"
        },
        address_3: {
          required: "Please enter your address"
        },
        postcode: {
          required: "Please enter your postcode"
        },
        city: {
          required: "Please select your city"
        },
        state: {
          required: "Please select your state"
        },
        contact_number_home: {
          required: "Please enter your home number"
        },
        contact_number_mobile: {
          required: "Please enter your mobile number"
        },
        signatureError: {
          required: "Please provide your signature"
        },
      }
    });

    // validate fields in 1st tab
    $('#next-btn').click(function() {
      if ($("#register-form").validate().element('#email') && $("#register-form").validate().element('#password') && $("#register-form").validate().element('#password-confirm')) {
        nextTab.find('a').trigger('click');
      } else {}
    });

    // validate fields in 2nd tab
    $('#next-btn2').click(function() {
      if ($("#register-form").validate().element('#full_name') && $("#register-form").validate().element('#nric') && $("#register-form").validate().element('#address_1') && $("#register-form").validate().element('#address_2') && $("#register-form").validate().element('#address_3') && $("#register-form").validate().element('#postcode') &&
        $("#register-form").validate().element('#city') && $("#register-form").validate().element('#state') && $("#register-form").validate().element('#contact_number_home') &&
        $("#register-form").validate().element('#contact_number_mobile') && $("#register-form").validate().element('#existing_customer')
      ) {
        nextTab.find('a').trigger('click');
      } else {}
    });

    // validate signature input in 3rd tab
    $('#submit').click(function() {
      if ($("#register-form").validate().element('#signatureError')) {
        alert("Success");
      } else {
        alert("Failure");
      }
    });
```

Comment: Maybe check that it’s not all white? I can’t see any other possible validation.

Comment: Check the documentation for `SignatuePad`. I would assume it exposes some events you can hook to, such as a notification that the user has filled in their signature. Then you can set a flag on the field which set it as valid. You may also need to write a custom validator for the validate library to read that flag, but there's lots of documentation on how to do that already; it's just 2 lines of code.

Comment: Yeah I am having a hard time as this form is done by my colleague so I need to understand how he declared the signature pad.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [signature_pad](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) by Szymon Nowak then it looks like you set it up correctly.

**Edit:** OK, I got the signature field to be part of validation. You need to not ignore hidden fields.

Do not validate the error message, LOL. Validate the actual field.

Also, I added a custom validator to handle validating the signature pad, but since it sets the value of the hidden signature field when you hit save, we only need to validate the signature.

### Helpful links

- https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/
- https://www.sitepoint.com/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/
- [jQuery Validate - Enable validation for hidden fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466643/jquery-validate-enable-validation-for-hidden-fields)

---

## Example

```js
let $form = $("#register-form");
let canvas = document.querySelector('.signature-pad');
let signatureSaveButton = document.getElementById('saveSignature');
let signatureResetButton = document.getElementById('resetSignature');
let signatureInput = document.querySelector('input[name="signature"]');

// Initialize a new signaturePad instance.
let signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);

// Clear signature pad.
signatureResetButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  signaturePad.clear();
  signatureInput.value = '';
  event.preventDefault();
  return false; // prevent submission...
});

// Save signature pad as data url.
signatureSaveButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  let signatureBlank = signaturePad.isEmpty();
  if (!signatureBlank) {
    signatureUrl = signaturePad.toDataURL();
    signatureInput.value = signatureUrl;
    $("div.error-messages span").html(''); // Clear messages
  }
  $(signatureInput).valid(); // Call validation on the field after hitting "Save"
  event.preventDefault();
  return false; // prevent submission...
});

// Not used, because this field has no name. Also, we want to use this
// to set the underlying (hidden) signature field...
$.validator.addMethod('signaturePresent', function(value, element) {
  console.log('Checking...');
  return this.optional(element) || signaturePad.isEmpty();
}, "Please provide your signature...");

// Validate registration tab before moving to the next tab
$form.validate({
  ignore: [], // This is important! We want to validate hidden fields.
  rules: {
    signature: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    signature: {
      required: "Please provide your signature"
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $("div.error-messages span").html(''); // Clear messages
    console.log('Submitting form...');
    //form.submit(); <-- UNCOMMENT TO ACTUALLY SUBMIT
  },
  invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
    console.log('INVALID!');
    // 'this' refers to the form
    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    if (errors) {
      var message = errors == 1
        ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
        : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
      $("div.error-messages span").html(message);
      $("div.error").show();
    } else {
      $("div.error").hide();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
padding: 2em;
}

.signature-pad {
  display: block;
  border: thin solid grey;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}

form .error {
  color: #F00;
}

.error-messages {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/signature_pad/1.5.3/signature_pad.min.js"></script>
<form id="register-form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
      <label for="signatureInput">Signature</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
      <canvas class="display-block signature-pad" style="touch-action: none;"></canvas>
      <div>
        <button id="resetSignature" class="btn btn-sm" style="background-color: lightblue;">Reset</button>
        <button id="saveSignature" class="btn btn-sm" style="background-color: #fbcc34;">Save</button>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="signature" id="signatureInput">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
      <input type="hidden" name="registrationFor" value="customer">
      <button type="submit" id="submit" class=" btn next-button bjsh-btn-gradient text-right">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="error-messages"><strong>Messages:</strong><br/><span></span></div>
```

Comment: I used the pad from szmet

Comment: @LordJesus: Yes, that is his username.

Comment: The code is a little bit long, I can't detect what new line that you added. Do you mind hightlighting it?

Comment: @LordJesus: Well, you did not use an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so I am not entirely sure. But as long as you included the required libraries, your validations should work just fine. I updated the response to include changes.

Comment: Oops , I did include the first few lines in my script originally. Please checked my edited post to confirm.

Comment: So I tested your answer, but the alert trigger is not fired in either case. My version of signature pad import is `2.3.2`. Not sure if it matters.

Comment: @LordJesus I believe I figured it out. I completely changed the code to only validate the signature portion of the form, since I do not have or care about any other field.

Comment: I figured it out although it's not the same as yours. I basically just check `signaturePad.isEmpty()` and it will check if the pad is signed or not.

Comment: @LordJesus I added a custom `signaturePresent` validator, but I did not use it, because you can just validate if you saved a signature to the hidden field.

Comment: I mean, my way is easier since `SignaturePad` is declared already. Just use it. But thanks for your help. Maybe change your answer to it and I'll mark it