# How to Get Typescript to Ignore a line of code?

Tags: jquery, typescript, jquery-validate

I am using jquery & jquery validate. I am also using typescript with the appropriate type files to go with it but when I do this line of code I get an error

```
  $('#form').validate().settings.ignore = [];
```

Error   TS2322  (TS) Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

This peice of code seem to be valid and does work. Maybe it has changed to something else but I have not found anything else that would work.

Comment: can you try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466643/jquery-validate-enable-validation-for-hidden-fields#:~:text=validate().,the%20form%20element%20via%20the%20%24.

Answer (score 12):

You can disable typescript in line by using ts-expect-error comments:

```js
  // @ts-expect-error
  $('#form').validate().settings.ignore = [];
```

You can read more about this [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#-ts-expect-error-comments).